# How do I display posts ordered by a date custom field?

Tags: posts, custom-field, order, date

I'm trying to show post order by a date custom field that are displayed like this:

```
    Year
     Month
       Custom field post info(date, time, venue, and category)
       Title
```

I found this function in the forum and modified it a little bit, and works great to sort out and display by year, month and date, but now that I have the posts sorted out, I'd like to add the title of each post and the rest of the info
So what I need is either a way to display that info inside one of those foreach statemets OR to have an array of ordered post IDs (I think that option would be easier for me)

```
<?php

        $posts = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'meta_key'  => 'fecha',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'meta_type' => 'DATE'
        ));

        $group_posts = array();

        if( $posts ) {

            foreach( $posts as $post ) {

                $date = CFS()->get( 'fecha' );

                $date = new DateTime($date);

                $year = $date->format('Y');
                $month = $date->format('F');

                $group_posts[$year][$month][] = array($post, $date);

            }

        }

        foreach ($group_posts as $yearKey => $years) {

            echo $yearKey;
            echo '<br>';

            foreach ($years as $monthKey => $months) {

                echo $monthKey;
                echo '<br>';

                foreach ($months as $postKey => $posts) {

                    echo $posts[1]->format('d-m-Y');
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo $posts[0]->title;
                    echo '<br>';
                }

            }

        }

    ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You should already have that information - you are adding the whole `$post` to `$group_posts`, so you can get all the information from it when you are displaying it in your `foreach($months...)` loop. `$posts[0]` is the post iteself and you are already getting the title: `echo $posts[0]->title;`, so you can also get any other information  from it as normal.

Comment: For some reason the   `echo $posts[0]->title;`  didn't return anything so I was a little bit confused. Ended up solving it in a different way

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out afterwards.
Ended up using a different approach, I'm posting it in case someone has the same issue

```
 <?php

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');


    $posts_by_date_field = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'fecha',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_type' => 'DATE'
    ));


    if ($posts_by_date_field->have_posts()) : while ($posts_by_date_field->have_posts()) : $posts_by_date_field->the_post();

            // LOOP

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $date = CFS()->get('fecha');

    if ($date >=  $today) :


            $date = new DateTime($date);


            $year = $date->format('Y');
            $month = $date->format('F');

            if ($aux_year != $year) {
                ?>
                <div class="anio"> <?php echo $year; ?> </div>
                <?php
            }

            if ($aux_month != $month) {

                ?>
                <div class="mes"> <?php echo $mes ?> </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

            <div class="metaData">

           <p> <?php the_title(); ?></p>

                <p> <?php echo  CFS()->get('fecha'); ?> </p>
                <p> <?php echo CFS()->get('hora'); ?> </p>
                <p> <?php echo CFS()->get('lugar'); ?> </p>
            </div>

            <?php
            $aux_year = $year;
            $aux_month = $month;

             endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
```